# How can I display a pdf with pdftron using npm

Tags: javascript, pdf, npm, client-side, pdftron

1. pdftron/webviewer is installed

   ```
    "dependencies": {
        "@pdftron/webviewer": "^7.3.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "mongoose": "^5.9.7",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
        "pug": "^2.0.4"
    }
   ```
2. Webviewer static files have been copied to the public folder
3. JavaScript in **index.html** file attempts to load a pdf

   Welcome to webviewer
        
        
        
        
            import WebViewer from '@/webviewer'

   ```
        WebViewer({
            path: '/webviewer',
            initialDoc: 'https://pdftron.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/pl/demo-annotated.pdf'
        }, 
        document.getElementById('viewer')).then(instance => {})    
     </script>
   ```
4. pdf file does not display, what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Hi. Would it be possible to show screenshot of your console and network tab? Would it also be possible to provide a link to your repository?

Comment: Here is the [repository] (https://github.com/ashe-senkatuuka/pdf-display) @Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank-you for sharing a link to your repository.

From following this guide: https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/get-started/manually/

Please try doing the following:

1. Please copy and paste webviewer.min.js from the pdftron webviewer node module to /public/webviewer
2. in your custom.js, please remove the line that imports from webviewer
3. in your index.html, please add this script tag before that calls your custom.js file:
   `<script src='./webviewer/webviewer.min.js'></script>`

Edit:
I noticed that there is a 404 on the network tab when I load up your application which led me to think that the set up of the library was not integrated correctly.